# Pytorch Memory efficient implementation of indexed matrix multiplication

Tags: python, matrix, memory, pytorch, multiplication

i am searching for a memory efficient implementation of indexed matrix multiplication in pytorch. Lets say we have given a tensor A with shape b1xnxd, a tensor B with shape b2xmxd, and two index vectors ind and ind2 with shape b3.
I want to calculate the following memory efficiently:

```
A2 = A[ind] # shape b3xnxd
B2 = B[ind2] # shape b3xmxd
result = torch.matmul(A2,B2.transpose(2,1)) # shape b3xnxm
```

The problem is when b3>>b or b3>>b2, then the first two lines consume a lot of memory but a lot of the entries of that tensors are the same. Is there a method in pytorch that prevents that? Is there maybe a version of the first two lines where the resulting tensor only stores pointers to the entries of A and B?

Comment: i found a solution myself by using an optimized version of einsum:

`import opt_einsum as oe`

`ind_ = to_one_hot(ind, A.shape[0], dtype=A.dtype)`
`ind2_ = to_one_hot(ind2, B.shape[0], dtype=B.dtype)`

`result = oe.contract("x n d, b x, y m d, b y -> b n m", A,ind_,B,ind2_)`

Comment: Can you give a complete example,  I have a similar problem except only one of the batch of matrices is indexed and the other are vectors. 

Do you use something else than `torch.nn.functional.one_hot(x)` ? The one-hot matrix also gets quite big if b3 and b are large which seems potentially problematic.

Comment: Our problem is basically to have an indexed nn.Linear where we pass in a vector of features and a vector of indexes and the layer looks up the weight based on the index. We can use bmm for this but it is an order of magnitude slower than Linear.

Comment: the to_one_hot looks like this:
`def to_one_hot(labels, anz, dtype=torch.long):`
    `one_hot = torch.zeros(labels.shape[0], anz, device=labels.device, dtype=dtype)`
    `one_hot[torch.arange(labels.shape[0]), labels] = 1`
    `return one_hot`

Comment: and yes, the result from to_one_hot has shapes b3xb1 and b3xb2 but thats better than shape b3xnxd and shape b3xmxd

Comment: if only one matrix is indexed you can remove e.g. the ind2_ calculation and do only the ind_ calculation

Comment: i guess the best way to do it would be to write a custom cuda kernel that does the calculation